# How to check backfill property of materialized view after its creation in database?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer, adx

I have created the materialized view in ADX with backfill property set . If I have to check the backfill property after its creation, How can I check it using the kusto command .
Example :

```
    .create async ifnotexists materialized-view with (**backfill=true, docString="Asset Trends",effectiveDateTime=datetime(2022-06-08)**) AssetTrend on table Variables {
Variables | summarize Normal = countif(value<=1), CheckSUM = countif(value>1 and value<=250), OutofSpecification = countif(value>250 and value<=500), MaintenanceRequired = countif(value>500 and value<=750), Failure = countif(value>750 and value<=1000) by bin(timestamp,1s)  , model, objectId, tenantId, variable }
```

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to find?

Comment: In production , I want to check  with which date the data has been backfilled in ADX database but I am not able to find any property to find out this information .

Answer (score 1):

**Update (following Yifat's comment):**

```
.show materialized-view MyMV
    | project EffectiveDateTime
```

| EffectiveDateTime |
| --- |
| 2022-08-29T11:25:48.2667521Z |

---

Search for the relevant `ClientActivityId` and then run this:

```
.show commands 
| where ClientActivityId == ...
| project ResourcesUtilization.ScannedExtentsStatistics
| evaluate bag_unpack(ResourcesUtilization_ScannedExtentsStatistics)  
| distinct *
```

| MaxDataScannedTime | MinDataScannedTime | ScannedExtentsCount | ScannedRowsCount | TotalExtentsCount | TotalRowsCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-29T11:25:52.0952791Z | 2022-08-29T11:25:48.2667522Z | 8 | 120000000 | 8 | 120000000 |

Here is the information from the table the MV was based on:

```
.show table r100k details 
| project TotalExtents, TotalRowCount, MinExtentsCreationTime, MaxExtentsCreationTime
```

| TotalExtents | TotalRowCount | MinExtentsCreationTime | MaxExtentsCreationTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 120000000 | 2022-08-29T11:25:48.2667522Z | 2022-08-29T11:25:52.0952791Z |

Comment: So ,as per my understanding , we need to analyze backfill date from MaxDateScannedTime and MinDataScannedTime values . Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Seems so. Take a look at the info I just added to the answer

Comment: When the command completes and the view is created successfully, it is entirely backfilled based on the `effectiveDateTime` in the command. If you're trying to find a way to know what was the `effectiveDateTime` used *after* the command completed, you can either use `.show journal` or examine the `EffectiveDateTime` column in `.show materialized-view` command. Is this the information you are looking for?